# How to make postgres listen on the container's new exposed port (not 5432)?

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose

I try to initialize a database with Go.
I use port 5433 at postgres:alpine because 5432 is already taken by another microservice app.

```golang
func Init() {
    DB, err = gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{
        DSN: "host=url_db user=gorm password=gorm dbname=gorm port=5433 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Tokyo",
    }), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    autoMigration()
}
```

```yaml
  url_db:
    build: 
      context: ./api/services/url/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: "url_db"
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_USER: gorm
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: gorm
      POSTGRES_DB: gorm
      POSTGRES_HOST: url_db
    ports:
      - 5433:5433
```

You can confirm that only 5432 is exposed [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/b9c080857b880202ebd23c59d33fe86d7a70fea3/13/alpine/Dockerfile).

I tried to expose 5433 by creating a new Dockerfile like this.

```
FROM postgres:alpine
EXPOSE 5433
```

But I got this error.

```
failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=url_db user=gorm database=gorm`: dial error (dial tcp 172.19.0.3:5433: connect: connection refused)
```

This comment:

Simply exposing the port on the docker image won't do anything unless postgres is actually configured to listen on that port. – super 5 mins ago

that teaches me the title(How can I expose a new port(not 5432) at postgres:alpine image?) is not the point, so I updated the title.

How to make postgres listen on the container's new exposed port (not 5432)?

Comment: Simply exposing the port on the docker image won't do anything unless postgres is actually configured to listen on that port.

Comment: @super Thank you. I updated the question title because I realize exposing a new port is not the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options:

**Option 1: Define own postgresql.conf**

```yaml
  url_db:
    build: 
      context: ./api/services/url/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: "url_db"
    command: postgres -c "config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf"
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_USER: gorm
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: gorm
      POSTGRES_DB: gorm
      POSTGRES_HOST: url_db
    ports:
      - 5433:5433
    volumes:
      - /path/to/config:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
```

Postgres has an example config at `/usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample` within the container.

To get the config run:

```sh
docker run -i --rm postgres cat /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample > my-postgres.conf
```

**Option 1: Overwrite the RUN command**

```yaml
  url_db:
    build: 
      context: ./api/services/url/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: "url_db"
    command: postgres -c port=5433
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_USER: gorm
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: gorm
      POSTGRES_DB: gorm
      POSTGRES_HOST: url_db
    ports:
      - 5433:5433
```

Comment: The second one looks more beautiful so I adopt that. Now it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple containers that are internally listening on the same port, so long as they're mapped to different ports on the host (if they're published at all).  In your example, you can set

```yaml
url_db:
  image: postgres:latest
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: gorm
    et: cetera
  ports:
    - 5433:5432
```

Connections from outside Docker reach the remapped port, on `<host ip>:5433`.  Connections between Docker containers use the standard service port, on `url_db:5432`.  These connections ignore (and don't require) `ports:`.

"Expose" in modern Docker means almost nothing; it is most valuable as documentation in an image showing what port(s) the service normally uses.  You can in theory ask Compose to [`expose:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose) additional ports without modifying the image, but there's no practical effect from doing so.

Comment: I didn't come up with that. That looks the most beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For Docker Compose assuming we want to change port to 5433

An alternative to doing this is to do the following in your docker-compose.yml file

1. you can mount the postgres data into a volume in your directory in this case ./db

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.14-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: iam
    ports:
      - 5433:5433
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

1. Find the postgresql.conf file, then search the `port`
2. change the port to

```
port = 5433             # (change requires restart)
```